# How can I create my own minifed openlayers js file?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to create my own minified openlayers js file with only the relevant classes my app used (including some custom class).

Is there a way to know by using the full openlayers.js file which are the ones I need to include in my custom build (instead doing trial and error and start deleting files and see which breaks my app) ?

Comment: I don't believe that there is anything in openlayers that supports this, so this probably would be better on stackoverflow (since its not GIS specific). In any case, are you confident that your tests exercise everything a user could do? If not, given its interpreted, I don't see how you can do the required code flow checks statically.

Comment: I've created a Python script to automate step 1 of @Devdatta's answer; feel free to give it a try and report problems. It's available on [github](https://github.com/kryger/jslib-custom-builder/blob/master/main-ol.py)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always successfully used Custom Builds Profiles to create custom OpenLayers Deployments.

There is a detailed explanation available here: [Custom build Profiles](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html#custom-build-profiles)

These are the steps I follow:

- Go through my Code and see which classes I'm using. Basically look for any class which you are using like `new OpenLayers.ClassName()`. Add these classes to the profile.
- The builder will look through the OpenLayers Code and automatically include those dependencies in the build.
- The only exception to this is the Vector Classes. If you are using Vector Layers, you need to provide all three renderes, since OpenLayers dynamically selects the appropriate renderer.

Comment: Cool , work like a charm !

Comment: damn link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial 
[Creating a custom OpenLayers build by profiling usage](http://mrdanadams.com/2012/custom-openlayers-build/#.WQLGujpRU0O)